# Backbone.js modeling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, modeling, backbone-events

I'm new to backbone.js, and trying to figure something out, I have the following objects currently:
**A TodoItem model**
**A TodoItemView view**
**A TodoCollection collection**

I add a bunch of TodoItems to the TodoCollection, which creates TodoItemViews for each, this renders a basic list of todo items. Now, when I click on a todo item, I want to open a new tab with all the data for that todo item, in a form (i.e, editable), and a Save button.

I'm trying to figure out how to model this.. should the TodoItemView have a click event which:

1. opens a tab and fills up all the info and somehow binds events
   from that new tab to functions within it? (almost certainly wrong)
2. create a new EditableTodoItemView, whose render opens a new tab,
   click on the TodoItemView creates a new EditableTodoItemView and then
   forgets about it (better, I think)

I'm assuming the EditableTodoItemView should reference the original model, i.e, the TodoItem should be shared between EditableTodoItemView and TodoItemView. No new collection needs to be created, the EditableTodoItemView calls backbone.sync() when the user hits save.

Likewise, I assume that when I create a new TodoItem, I push it into the TodoCollection, which creates a TodoItemView for it and possibly automatically creates an EditableTodoItemView if the item is new (i.e, has default data).

Does this make sense? Anything else I should be thinking about?

Comment: have you tried to follow the To-Do app example on the backbonejs website?

Comment: Do you mean open in a new browser tab?! Javascript running in the page for the new tab won't have access to any of the Backbone.js objects you created on the other page.

YOU are creating the views, right? As far as I know there is no automatic view creation of any kind built in to Backbone.js.

Comment: @erturne: no, I meant a jquery tab.

Comment: @TomTu: Yes, both editing and viewing are built into the same view there because it's so simplistic. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to switch between multiple views is a `Backbone.Router`. You can use it like this:

```
var TodoRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "edit/:id":  "edit",   // matches http://yourapp.com/#edit/1234
    ".*":        "index",  // matches http://yourapp.com/#everything-else
  },

  edit: function(id) {
    item = TodoCollection.get(id);
    this.view = EditableTodoItemView({model: item});
    $("#main").html(this.view.render().el);
  },

  index: function() {
    //...
  }

});
```

Then just run `window.router = new TodoRouter; Backbone.history.start();` where you start the application. Make sure, your TodoCollection is fetched, before you run this. You can use  `TodoCollection.bind("reset", _.once(function(){Backbone.history.start()}));`.